# Vertical Align Anchor with :After

Tags: css

I have a simple anchor as follows:

```
<a href="#">News</a>
```

I would like to add an "+" sign on the right so I used ":after".

ONLINE EXAMPLE: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/IDakn

But I need the "+" sign to be larger then the anchor text.

The problem is in this case the text and the "+" sign are not vertically aligned.

UPDATE

As mentioned by Dale using line-height solves the problem but:

1. If I use line-height: 1.5rem it works fine - http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/ogriw;
2. If I use line-height: 1.5 then it does not work - http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/IDakn;

Why? Shouldn't line-height be specified without units?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS line-height would be the problem here. Give the anchor a line-height of about 20px to make it align with the text.

```
a{line-height:20px;}
```

Comment: This give the anchor and the :after + the same line-height so they will align.

Comment: I tried using font-size and line-height in rem and it works ... But when I use font-size in rem and line-height without units, so line-height: 1.5 it does not work. Any idea why this happens? See example: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/IDakn

Comment: @Shapper you are giving different font-sizes to the original element and pseudo element. if you give line-height without units then the line-height will be with respect to their font-sizes. Hence, you can't see any change. That is why give line-height a unit like `px`, so that line height will be same for both elements independent of their font sizes. I hope you understand my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating, but you can use `line-height` on your `:after` to adjust the vertical align:

```
  &:after {     
    line-height:0.5em;       
  }
```